Is there an order preserving bijection (order isomorphism) between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$?
Here, an order preserving bijection is a bijection between two totally ordered sets $f:(A,\leq)\to(B,\leq)$, where $\forall x< y$ in $A$, $f(x)< f(y)$.
We want to find if there is an order preserving bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. Both orders are the order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.
I guess the answer is false, but I have no idea on how to prove this. This is a strange question, because $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is constructed by "algebra", but the order is by "analysis". I don't know how to connect them.

In fact the answer is yes, for a very "coarse" reason:

Any two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are order-isomorphic.

This was proved by Cantor. Note that Cantor's argument is completely explicit; that said, the isomorphism built depends on the choice of enumeration of the linear orders involved and does not have a short description. We can ask whether "algebraically describable" isomorphisms exist, and here things do tend to follow your intuition. For example, there is no polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients which gives an order-preserving bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, although (unless I'm missing something) this is a bit tricky to prove.

It’s not horribly difficult to prove. Let $P(x)$ be such a polynomial. There are infinitely many rational $r$ such that $P(r)$ is rational. Therefore, $P$ has rational coefficients. If we are taking $P : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, this is immediately disqualifying as $\sqrt{2}$ isn’t in the range. If we are taking $P$ the other way, then $P(\sqrt{2}) \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $P(\sqrt{2}) = P(-\sqrt{2})$, which contradicts injectivity. So no polynomial constitutes a bijection between the two.
